# Format of string in C# use regex

Tags: c#, regex, string

String source

> “/jame/ng2ih4cj3ekk8/haki/g8o7o3”

How to group them:

> jame,ng,2
>
> jame,ih,4
>
> jame,cj,3
>
> jame,ekk,8
>
> haki,g,8
>
> haki,o,7
>
> haki,o,3

And this is my code adn result:

```
Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
MatchCollection mc;
string source = "/jame/n2i4c3e8/haki/g8o7o3";

string pattern = @"(/[A-Z_a-z]+/)|([A-Z_[ạảàáãăắẳằặẵâấẩầậẫóỏòọõôốổồộỗơớởờợỡéèẻẹẽêếềểệễúùủụũưứừửựữíìỉịĩýỳỷỵỹđ_ẠẢÀÁÃĂẮẲẰẶẴÂẤẨẦẬẪÓỎÒỌÕÔỐỔỒỘỖƠỚỞỜỢỠÉÈẺẸẼÊẾỀỂỆỄÚÙỦỤŨƯỨỪỬỰỮÍÌỈỊĨÝỲỶỴỸĐ_a-z]+_?[0-9_/._0-9]+)";
Regex myRegex = new Regex(pattern);
mc = myRegex.Matches(source);
foreach (Match m in mc)
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

> /jame/
>
> ng2
>
> ih4
>
> cj3
>
> ekk8/
>
> haki/
>
> g8
>
> o7
>
> o3

Comment: Are those groups `n2i4c3e8` and `g8o7o3` always a even number of chars?

Comment: In my case, some time they are `ns2is5cs6eu7` and `gw0ue7kshd8`.
My ex is `string-number-string-number-string-number`

Comment: instead of all those characters (`[ạảàáã...]`)  use `[\p{L}_]`

Comment: Use `Regex.Matches(s, @"(?<=/(\w+)/[^/]*?)(\p{L}+)([0-9]+)").Cast<Match>().Select(p => string.Format("{0},{1},{2}", p.Groups[1].Value, p.Groups[2].Value, p.Groups[3].Value))`

Comment: but some case my string source contains UNICODE. ` [\p{L}_]` can perform? Pls

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew let me try now

Comment: I edited the comment - see http://ideone.com/QEpw5L

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew. Thank so much your support! I went your link. Tried it work. The Result so good. Have a nice day! (y)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This splits the source in groups of two items ("key" and value) and breaks the value in several substrings ending with numbers.

```
var source = "/jame/ng2ih4cj3ekk8/haki/g8o7o3";
var results = source.Split("/".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select ((value, index) => new {value, index})
    .GroupBy(item => item.index / 2, item => item.value);

foreach (var result in results)
{
    var items = Regex.Replace(result.Last(), @"\d", match =>
    {
        return "," + match.Value + Environment.NewLine;
    });

    foreach (var item in items.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray(),
                                     StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        Console.WriteLine(result.First() + "," + item);
}
```

However, I think I can do better. Hold my beer.

**EDIT**: this version takes advantage of the `MatchEvaluator` argument in the Regex.Replace call to format the output string:

```
var source = "/jame/ng2ih4cj3ekk8/haki/g8o7o3";
var result = Regex.Replace(source, @"/(?<group>.*?)/(?<value>[^/]+)", match =>
{
    return Regex.Replace(match.Groups["value"].Value, @"(?<letter>\D+)(?<number>\d)",sub =>
    {
        return match.Groups["group" ].Value + "," +                // "jame,"
               sub  .Groups["letter"].Value + "," +                // "ng,"
               sub  .Groups["number"].Value + Environment.NewLine; // "2<CRLF>"
    });
});

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: WOWWWW!!!. Thanks man. I worked, this home work i try to got it for a week but my code doesn't work. :( Thanks my friend <3

Comment: It so helpfull (y) Thank for supporting me!

Comment: Any reason for using `\D+` instead of `\w+`?

Comment: @BurnsBA, no particular reason; it seems that OP needs to deal with some unicode issues, so he can change it accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
string source = "/jame/n2i4c3e8/haki/ns2is5cs6eu7";
var splitted = Regex.Split(source, @"(?=\/[a-z]+\/)");

foreach (var word in splitted.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)))
{
    var cutted = word.Split(new[] { '/' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    var baseWord = cutted.First();

    foreach(var end in Regex.Split(cutted.Last(), @"([a-z]+\d)").Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)))
        Console.WriteLine($"/{baseWord}/{Regex.Match(end, @"[a-z]+")},{Regex.Match(end, @"\d+")} ");
}
```

Comment: Thanks man so much. OMG, It work. But if I want to result have form above like that, NON `/` and it have `,` How to do it:

`jame,ng,2


jame,ih,4


jame,cj,3


jame,ekk,8


haki,g,8


haki,o,7


haki,o,3`